# can't run react native with emulator android on Atom

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, atom-editor

i have an iphone and i don't have a macbook so i have to use an emulator android to test my application react-native

When I type the command : react-native run-android

I got 2 errors:

1- [Failed to launch emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Wgg.png)

2- [error sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuDbr.png)

Error #1 :

My emulator is open :

[Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBaFP.png)

I use the Piexel 3L API 26 with Android 8.0
[Pixel 3L](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpkWx.png)

what more do i need to do?

Error #2 :

This is my path SDK :
[Path sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeZ2y.png)

So in android studio i have the same path :
[Android studio path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyYhA.png)

And my path is in environment variables :
[Environnement variables path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qb9fI.png)

thanks for wanting to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the first error but I hope that by solving the second one, you'll be able to run everything successfully.

The error #2 specifically says to create a file called `local.properties` in the root of your android project with the following contents:

```
sdk.dir=YOUR_PATH_HERE
```

You only have to replace `YOUR_PATH_HERE` with your Android SDK path, which you seem to have found according to your screenshot.

Comment: Now that say : The SDK directory 'C:\Users\Pierre-Olivier\Desktop\test123\projtest\android\"C:\Users\Pierre-Olivier\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"' does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

hmmmm that work but not for all

I got another error:

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

[Gradlew.bat error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpkwW.png)